# iOS Facebook Status Location

Tags: ios, facebook, location

I'm confused as to how I use a location in a user's status. I see there is a place field, but I dont' know how to use it. The instructions just say an object, it doesn't specify at all what object it wants and in what format it wants. Can anyone give me a hand on posting a status with a location on it?

This is my code now:

```
- (void)postWithMessage:(NSString *)message image:(UIImage *)image location:(CLLocation *)location {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSString *path = @"feed";
    [params setObject:@"status" forKey:@"type"];
    if (message && ![message isEqualToString:@""]) [params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
    if (image) {
        path = @"me/photos";
        [params setObject:@"photo" forKey:@"type"];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [params setObject:imageData forKey:@"source"];
    }
    if (location) {
        //Stole this from iOS hackbook that Facebook wrote, but it wasn't helpful.
        NSString *centerLocation = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude];
        [params setObject:centerLocation forKey:@"center"];
    }


    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:path andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [creating a stream post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) list a parameter `place` whose value is the *Facebook Page ID of the location*.  You can find these place ids via [search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching) or [querying the place FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place/).

You should also use the Graph api path `me/feed` in this case.

Although unrelated to your question, in the `if (image)` branch you add a parameter `type` which isn't documented in the [section on posting a photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos).

Answer (score 0):

For adding a place, you need to provide place ID known by Facebook currently. For that you can get the nearest places which returns ID as well and then add the one which you want as the place.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed something, as i remember, the hackbook use the location to find the place id and then put it in parameter "place".

To do so, 
1. you need to do a searching:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?
  q=coffee&
  type=place&
  center=40.7167,-74&
  distance=1000
```

//copy from facebook :]

1. select a place
2. post the post with place id
   Noted that, as I tried before you cant select a place with a distance more than 1000m
   (not sure about it now, tried long long time ago)

Answer (score 0):

to test this you can try here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/
in the field paste this line example "search?q=spa&type=place&center=40.7167,-74& distance=1000"

```
then you will see results like 
{
  "data": [
    {
      "location": {
        "street": "221 Canal Street, Room 301", 
        "city": "New York", 
        "state": "NY", 
        "country": "United States", 
        "zip": "10013", 
        "latitude": 40.71761, 
        "longitude": -73.99933
      }, 
      "category": "Spas/beauty/personal care", 
      "name": "CiCi Beauty Spa", 
      "id": "180068255444372"
    }, 

etc...

you can then post status like 
("message", "im here guys"); // your message
("place", "180068255444372"); // the id of the place 

in the tool field "me/feed"
```

in the tool change the method to POST then add field parameter for "message" and "place" to test it.